# Need to inform user to upgrade Java

Tags: java

I've recently dropped Java 6 compatibility with a program that I've been working on for a few years. I've tried to make a popup that informs users that the must upgrade in the main class, but when the jar is run on a Java 6 system, it fails before ever getting there due to version incompatibility.

Is there a way to pop a warning message at some earlier point on Java 6 machines while still compiling to later versions? As it stands, users that try to open it will just be greeted with a silent failure.

Comment: Since you're packaging the application, could you include a notice (like in release notes, or on the download page) to say that Java 6 is no longer supported and that they should move to Java 7 or newer?  Trying to do that from the application would only work if you did so on the application that was still compatible with Java 6.

Comment: If your program is a single jar this might be a dumb idea, but you could make some kind of launcher jar that's compatible with 6 (or lower) and checks if the correct version is installed. Not sure what your demographic is, but simply including it in the release notes or something may be sufficient.

Comment: The launcher jar might end up being what I have to do, but I'm hoping for something cleaner. Unfortunately, a lot of my userbase is very technically limited, and many of them aren't even aware that Java has versions at all. Part of the reason I'm trying to make the notification is so that I can display simple instructions on how they can upgrade.

Answer (score 4):

Create a Java 6 facade Class that checks the current version of Java, and if it is Java6, then tell them they must upgrade. If the current version is >Java 6, then let them start the app.

You can detect the current version using the following code snippet:

`System.getProperty("java.version");`

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've messed with this a bit, and am having trouble figuring out how to make a single class that builds in J6 to launch with vs. the rest of the program building with J7. Could you point me to anything that might explain?

Comment: hrm... now that I think about it, can you launch a j7 jvm from a j6 jvm? You could write a script that calls the j6 facade, then depending on the output, call the j7 jar or exit.